# My WordPress blog address is shown to all my Gmail contacts: how to prevent?

Tags: gmail, privacy, wordpress, blog

My friend found my WordPress blog by importing *his* Gmail contacts into *his* WordPress blog. And I was in his contacts. Thus, WordPress shares my blog address automatically with all my Gmail contacts.

But I do not want this sharing. How to prevent this?

Comment: Use a different email address for your WordPress.com account?

Comment: What is your blog address? Are you using a gravatar account or a regular email?